# Error ( View.findViewById() must not be null ) en Adapter

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un viewpager, y un RecyclerView que instancia imagenes en un fragmento, para ello he implementado código de un proyecto de flexbox para android.
Las imagenes son pequeños botones ubicados bajo el viewpager

**FRAGMENTO**

```
class OneFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_one) {
    private  val adapter by lazy { AdapterWebView(this) }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //VIEWPAGER
        pagerw.isUserInputEnabled = false
        pagerw.adapter = adapter

        //RECYCLERVIEW
        val recyclerView = recycler_view
        val layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(activity)
        layoutManager.flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW
        layoutManager.justifyContent = JustifyContent.CENTER
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

        val divLikeContent = ArrayList<String>()
        var imgfast:String = "https://res.cloudinary.com/twenty20/private_images/t_standard-fit/v1521838666/photosp/465c3fcc-64ea-4aab-9439-e9c98959acf6/465c3fcc-64ea-4aab-9439-e9c98959acf6.jpg"
        divLikeContent.add(imgfast)
        divLikeContent.add(imgfast)


        val adapter = DivLikeAdapter(divLikeContent)

        if(pagerw != null){
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        }
    }

}
```

Todo funciona bien, el problema surgió por que decidí implementar un setOnClickListener a cada imagen para que al hacer clic en estas se cambie de pagina, esto implica que tenga que hacer referencia al pager lo cual genera el error

```
private val img: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView)  //No genera Problema, item es un layout con una imageview

private val pagerd: ViewPager2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pagerw)  //Produce el error, el pager se encuentra el fragmento
```

**ERROR**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.testlab.toptag, PID: 19312
    java.lang.NullPointerException: itemView.findViewById(R.id.pagerw) must not be null
        at com.testlab.toptag.one.DivLikeAdapter$DivItemViewHolder.<init>(DivLikeAdapter.kt:39)
        at com.testlab.toptag.one.DivLikeAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(DivLikeAdapter.kt:22)
        at com.testlab.toptag.one.DivLikeAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(DivLikeAdapter.kt:15)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
```

**ADAPTER**

```
class DivLikeAdapter(private val mItems: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DivLikeAdapter.DivItemViewHolder>() {
    
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DivLikeAdapter.DivItemViewHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)

        return DivItemViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DivItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.onBind(position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mItems.size
    }


    inner class DivItemViewHolder constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        (itemView) {
        //private val text: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text)
        private val img: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView)

        private val pagerd: ViewPager2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pagerw)   //ERROR



        fun onBind(position: Int) {

            Glide.with(itemView)
                .load(mItems[position]).into(img)


            img.setOnClickListener {
                pagerd.currentItem = position    //asigno a cada imagen el numero correspondiente de pagina del pager
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Al parecer el problema es exclusivamente por la referencia al pager, sin embargo no lo entiendo ya que este no es nulo. talvez el problema sea por que lo estoy referenciando de forma incorrecta.

Comment: Estas buscando un viewpager dentro de una imageView eso no es posible y es absurdo. dale el findviewbyid al contenedor del viewpager.

Comment: Se refiere a itemView verdad, en ese caso con que lo remplazo. @OsAndNoTi

Comment: no te sirvió mi respuesta?

Comment: Si funciono, pensé que ya había aceptado la respuesta, gracias por su apoyo y por las recomendaciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que estás buscando dentro un item un elemento que dices que está fuera de él. La solución más simple sería buscar el elemento dentro de su verdadero padre o en su defecto, dentro de la activity completa `activity.findViewById(R.id.pagerw)`. Pero esto es malo en términos de performance. Debes intentar usar `findViewById()` lo menos posible, en esto caso lo estás llamando cada vez que creas que un viewHolder y realmente no tienes ninguna necesidad de hacerlo.

**La solución más óptima es la siguiente:**

Primero agregas un parámetro al constructor del adapter

```
class DivLikeAdapter(
    private val mItems: ArrayList<String>,
    private val onItemClicked: (index: Int) -> Unit,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DivLikeAdapter.DivItemViewHolder>() { ... }
```

Luego escribes el callback en tu fragment y se lo pasas al constructor

```
val pagerd: ViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.pagerw)
val adapter = DivLikeAdapter(arrayListOf()) {
    pagerd.currentItem = it
}
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

Finalmente en el viewHolder creas un clickListener que llame al callback

```
fun onBind(position: Int) {
    Glide.with(itemView).load(mItems[position]).into(img)
    img.setOnClickListener { onItemClicked(position) }
}
```

**PD:** si vas a copiar código, por lo menos procura entenderlo. Esto `val mItems: ArrayList<String>` es una prueba de que copiaste tu adapter de uno que estaba hecho en java sin entender lo que significa.