# view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViews) must not be null

Tags: android, android-studio

He usado un recyclerview antes en una actividad, funciona perfecto ahí. Sin embargo ahora necesito usarlo en un fragmento, y no he logrado implementarlo correctamente.

```
view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViews) must not be null
```

Aparece como si fuera nulo, He visto unos tutoriales y lo implementan de esa forma.

**Fragment**

```
class ColaFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var recyclerAdapter: RecyclerAdapter

private lateinit var deletedCountry: String


private var countryList = mutableListOf<String>()
private var displayList = mutableListOf<String>()

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViews)   //AQUI MARCA EL ERROR
    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    ......
```

**XML**

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViews"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
   />
```

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.testlabx.navplay, PID: 22326
    java.lang.NullPointerException: view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViews) must not be null
        at com.testlabx.navplay.fmfeed.pager.ColaFragment.onCreateView(ColaFragment.kt:32)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:442)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2169)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1992)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
```

Alguien tiene idea de que puede estar pasando, si necesitan mas código avisarme por favor.

Comment: hola, ya hiciste esta pregunta hace no mucho. [Esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/433382/198326) es la respuesta que aceptaste

Comment: Hola, acabo de darme cuenta de mi error.
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
Estaba cargando la vista de otro fragmento, igual gracias por la recomendación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que indicas

> view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViews) must not be null

se debe a que en el layout `fragment_blank.xml` no existe el elemento con id `recyclerViews`, este elemento existe en tu proyecto pero en otra vista pero es necesario exista dentro de `fragment_blank.xml` ya que en esta vista buscas la referencia del recyclerView  con id `recyclerViews`

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViews)   //AQUI MARCA EL ERROR
    return view
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias tienes razón por eso era el error, ya lo pude resolver.